# HTML submit form without refresh page and display alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, alert

I want to submit the form to php, then the data will be updated to the database and alert box will be displayed.
Now, data had update the DB but the alert box didn't show up.
What is the problem of my code??
Thanks.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        function SubmitForm() {
        var category_id = $("#category_id").val();
        var category_name = $("#category_name").val();
        $.post("test.php", { category_id: category_id, category_name: category_name },
           function(data) {
             alert("Finish!");
           });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        category_id: <input type="text" name="category_id" id="category_id"/>
        category_name: <input type="text" name="category_name" id="category_name"/>
        <input type="button" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm();" value="Send" />
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['category_id'];
$b = $_POST['category_name'];


$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db("fyp", $link);
$sql = "INSERT INTO category (CID, Category) VALUES (".
         PrepSQL($a) . ", " .
         PrepSQL($b) . ")";

mysql_query($sql);

function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    // Quote
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

    return($value);
}
?>
```

Comment: use .done() to get the success or .fail() to get the failed response

Comment: why dont you use $.ajax to prperly configure all the parameters?

Comment: i am the beginner of javascript/php, not quite familiar about ajax.

Comment: user2108245 see the solution below.... it is just a shorthand notation and you can customize with multiple options. For examples look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $.post("test.php", { category_id: category_id, category_name: category_name })
      .done(
           function(data) {
               alert("Finish!");
           }
      );
```

Comment: try chaining `.fail(function() { alert("error"); })` to the end to see if the form is erroring

Comment: It looks as if something is not completing properly on your test.php page - try actually posting the variables to it (without ajax) and see if the page loads properly

Comment: i tried to modify the .php file.
<?php
$a = $_POST['category_id'];
$b = $_POST['category_name'];
?>

but still fail...

Comment: I think you may actually need to write something to the screen to get a success response, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740616/jquery-ajax-php-how-to-determine-if-the-php-code-executed-successfully

Answer (score 1):

You put three parameters there, it's just supposed to be two. You can try this instead:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    function SubmitForm() {
    var category_id = $("#category_id").val();
    var category_name = $("#category_name").val();
    $.post("test.php", { category_id: category_id, category_name: category_name })
    .done(function() {
      alert("Finish!");
    });
    }
</script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var category_id = $("#category_id").val();
    var category_name = $("#category_name").val();
    $.post("test.php", { category_id: category_id, category_name: category_name })
    .done(function(data) {
           alert("Finish!");
    });
}
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: 1) he's using a button, not submit. 2) his question isn't even complaining about redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Solution

```
    function SubmitForm() {
        var category_id = $("#category_id").val();
        var category_name = $("#category_name").val();
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "test.php", 
               data: { category_id: category_id, category_name: category_name }
        }).done (function() {
             alert("Finish");
        }).fail (function(status) {
            console.log(status);          
        });
```

Now inspect the data to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But still didnt pop up.
I tried to add a .fail() and the fail pop up showed.

Comment: Yeah then the problem is the response object is not returning a success. try console.log(data) in the fail. I am editing my answer to do that.